# ASP multiple queries to database server

Tags: asp.net, database, performance

We are having an ASP.Net Web app, where in we are to access a database server quite frequently.

Since we need to make multiple queries to the database, current approach that we are following is to get the data at one go at the time of connect and store this is as a dataset. This approach will just save us to make multiple queries to the database.

But, we won't be able to use database features like indexes or case insensitive searches on to dataset/dataview. This is now leading a poor performance.

So, I'm wondering is there any way by which we can enhance the performance. I personally am not liking the idea of storing the entire data on the web application. But being a novice in asp.net I am not able to think of any specific solution.

So any help in fixing this is really appreciated.

Comment: Good question presentation Vishal..

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, talking to the database server isn't going to cause you a performance issue. It may be that the scripts you are using are slow and that is your issue.
Do you have a script that is taking a long time to run, or a huge data set (millions of rows)?

Applications quite often make 5-10 DB calls per page and perform perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

A DataReader can provide you access to data in a very efficient manner, and in most cases it's actually faster than the DataSet.